# Change upload address of a sharepoint webpart project

Tags: visual-studio-2010, sharepoint-2010, web-parts

as i created my webpart project i accidentally entered a wrong URL to upload the webpart to the sharepoint. I am sure there is a way to change that address, but i just can't find it.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have a Farm Solution, you can change the same in the Site URL under Properties for the project.

Regards,
Nitin Rastogi

Comment: Yeah, basically found ich just like 2 mins ago... Rightclick Properties ain't the same as the property window... thanks :)